# Overlaying image on top of fullscreen applications in python

Tags: python, graphics

I would like to know how to display a python tkinter window overlay on a fullscreen application. Any ideas on how it is done?

I read other posts where it said DirectX needs to be hooked. I stumbled upon a program that exactly does what I am looking for : https://hudsight.com/

Any idea of how I can make a program like this in Python. I currently can overlay a transparent Tkinter window over windowed applications. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk

image_canvas = tk.Canvas(bg='#00ff00', width=100, height=100, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
img = tk.PhotoImage(file='Cross.png')
image_canvas.create_image(25, 25, image=img)

image_canvas.master.overrideredirect(True)
image_canvas.master.geometry('100x100+935+515')
#image_canvas.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (100, 100, 960, 540))
image_canvas.master.lift()
image_canvas.master.wm_attributes('-topmost', True)
image_canvas.master.wm_attributes('-disabled', True)
#image_canvas.master.wm_attributes('-alpha', True)
image_canvas.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "#00ff00")
image_canvas.pack()
image_canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please post and example of the code you have tried already?

Comment: Done! This snippet of code gets Cross.png to the center of the screen which basically is a crosshair. Works with windowed mode but not fullscreen mode